# manual managed hibernate does not write changes on exit

Tags: hibernate

I have a small program persisting an object via hibernate:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{

    System.out.println("starting");

    EntityManager em = CustomEntityManager.getEntityManagerFactory().createEntityManager();
    em.getTransaction().begin();
    try {
        Thing thing = new Thing();
        thing.setName("huhu");
        thing.setUuid(UUID.randomUUID().toString());
        em.persist(thing);
        em.flush();
        em.getTransaction().commit();
    }catch(Exception ex){
        System.err.println(ex.getLocalizedMessage());
    }

    em.close();


}
```

when I add a sleep(1000) to the end of the program, the `Thing` gets persisted. If not, it seems that the program exits before hibernate can write the changes to the actual database file.
Is there some additional flushing I have to to in the end or can I call some blocking function until all changes have been written?

Comment: Why rollback is in finally & not in catch; in finally you should close.

Comment: yeah that may be wrong too, but there does not happen a rollback right now anyway

Comment: Committed transactions aren't rolled back. In above code, you're commiting & then in finally block rollback is happening but there are no changes to rollback after last commit.